# Relative error of $\mathrm{z_0}$ with respect to z

Tags: numerical-methods, rounding-error

> Suppose that for a problem with solution $\mathrm{z}$, our approximated result was $\mathrm{z_0=175.002043}$ and the relative error committed $\mathrm{\frac{|\Delta z_0|}{|z|}} \le \mathrm{5x10^{-4}}$. Write the value of z.

As $\mathrm{z_0}$ has $\mathrm{9}$ significant digits, I could ensure that $\mathrm{\frac{|\Delta z_0|}{|z_0|}} \le \mathrm{5x10^{-9}}$, but how could I reach a value for z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are given more significant digits of $z_0$ than it makes sense with this relative error probably means that the excessive digits should be dropped, by rounding. So I assume that this problem is concerned with writing a quantity with error in the notation using $\pm$. In that case the conventions which I am used to dictate the following.

Find the absolute error and round it to a single significant digit (or two digits, if the first digit is $1$), so $|\Delta z_0|\approx 0.09$; round $z_0$ to the same precision as the rounded $|\Delta z_0|$, obtaining $175.00$; write down the answer as $z=175.00\pm0.09$.

If you didn't encounter anything like this before, then I probably misunderstood the assignment.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to write z=175.002±0.09? With this approach, the digit at the second decimal place  (considering that the absolute error is bounded above by $\mathrm{9x10^{-2}}$) would be unaltered
 .

Comment: @JP I was taught to keep exactly the same number of decimal places as in the uncertainty (thus, no), but conventions may vary from course to course.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightenment, I wasn't aware of that.